# Sending complex parameter with Alamofire Swift3 gets Status Code 500 error

Tags: swift, parameters, swift3, alamofire

I have very little experience with Alamofire and JSON things. I have searched a lot on the internet and tried my best before asking this question so please understand me.

I am trying to send a parameter with `.put` method using Alamofire.

When I test sending the parameter with **PostMan(Chrome Extension)**, everything is ok.

The parameter is like this

```
update_values : {"address":"Sanchaung", "phone":["095567890", "094272732"], "emergency_phone":[{"name":"someone", "phone":"3454234"},{"name":"sometwo", "phone":"3454234"}]}
```

> "address" is string, "phone" is array of string, "emergency_phone" is
>   array of Dictionary

I declare the parameter in swift3 like this

```
let ep : NSDictionary = [
            "name" : "someone",
            "phone" : "12345"
        ]

let uv : NSDictionary = [
            "address" : "Sanchaung",
            "phone" : ["123","1234"],
            "emergency_phone" : [ep,ep]
        ]

let parameters = [
            "update_values" : uv
        ]
```

Then send it with Alamofire like this

```
Alamofire.request("http://myLink.com/api/employees/10?auth_token=\(vc.userInform.auth_token)", method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch(response.result)
                {
            case .success(let JSON) :

            case .failure(let error) :

                print(" UPDATING ERROR IS \(error)")
            }
    }
```

Then I received status code 500 error

```
UPDATING ERROR IS responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(500))
```

Am I receiving that error because my parameter is not acceptable type?
**How can I send that parameter in proper way?**

Please help me with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
    let ep: [String: Any] = [
        "name" : "someone",
        "phone" : "12345"
    ]

    let uv: [String: Any] = [
        "address" : "Sanchaung",
        "phone" : ["123","1234"],
        "emergency_phone" : [ep,ep]
    ]

    let parameters = [
        "update_values" : uv
    ]
```

instead of your code.

You can compare the results of the json serialization with:

```
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

    print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work. I printed the JSNSerialization `json serializationOptional("{\n  \"update_values\" : {\n    \"phone\" : [\n      \"123\",\n      \"1234\"\n    ],\n    \"emergency_phone\" : [\n      {\n        \"phone\" : \"12345\",\n        \"name\" : \"someone\"\n      },\n      {\n        \"phone\" : \"12345\",\n        \"name\" : \"someone\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"address\" : \"Sanchaung\"\n  }\n}")` but I don't know what I can achieve by comparing the result.

Comment: Ok, contains your auth token spacial chars?

Comment: I serialized the uv and it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To be honest there might be several issues here - error 500 suggests that your parameters reached the server but it did not understand them and crashed.

Your params seems to be ok for me. But I'd suggest to check the headers used by postman like `"Content-Type" : "application/json"`. Try to replicate them in your code. It may happen that the server needs this header to determine its next action and lacking this info may result with failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added this line `.validate(contentType: ["application/json"])` but still receive the status code 500 error.

Comment: Maybe try adding it as a header so instead of a nil you will send `headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]`. The `.validate` function ensures that the `response` has this content type while we are trying to add the content type to the `request` itself

Comment: Thanks. I have added headers: `["Content-Type" : "application/json"]` but still unlucky.